# TypeError: Member "WETH" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IUniswapV2Router

Tags: uniswap, cpp-ethereum

My code below

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

contract MEVBot {
    address private constant uniswapRouter = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D; // Mainnet Uniswap V2 Router Address
    address private constant tokenToTrade =0xe945485c8F4b60c96Fa14f9D403ef76cBc29b0Fb; // Replace with the token address to trade
    uint private constant slippage = 5; // Custom slippage of 5%
    uint private constant maxTradingAmount = 1 ether; // Maximum amount of ETH to trade at once
    uint private constant maxTradingFee = 0.01 ether; // Maximum trading fee in ETH

    receive() external payable {}

    function start() public {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = IUniswapV2Router(uniswapRouter).WETH();
        path[1] = tokenToTrade;

        uint[] memory amounts = IUniswapV2Router(uniswapRouter).getAmountsOut(maxTradingAmount, path);
        uint expectedAmountOut = amounts[1] - (amounts[1] * slippage / 100);

        require(expectedAmountOut > maxTradingFee, "Trading fee is higher than expected profit");

        IUniswapV2Router(uniswapRouter).swapExactETHForTokens{value: maxTradingAmount}(expectedAmountOut, path, address(this), block.timestamp);

        // Wait for some time for the token price to increase
        // Sell the token for profit and withdraw the funds
        // ...
    }

    function stop() public {
        // Stop the bot from buying and selling tokens
        // ...
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        // Withdraw the funds from the bot
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you may have made a mistake while importing the Uniswap interface in your smart contract. To import the interface correctly, you should include the following code at the beginning of your contract:

```
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
```

Once you have imported the interface, you can use it in your contract code. For example, to obtain the WETH address, you can use the following code:

```
path[0] = IUniswapV2Router02(uniswapRouter).WETH();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you it helped but now it is giving me the license error even tho I've mentioned it correctly in my code. Sharing error below. Thank you for your help.

Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> @uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol

Comment: There's no error in the smart contract, but a warning. The smart contract will still function even with this warning. It's likely that the warning is being generated because the license is not specified in the interface. You can check the "IUniswapV2Router02.sol" file to see if the license is specified or not.